# Ho to fix error "not able to initialize final variable in static block"?

Tags: java

I have an error where I can "Not able to initialize final variable "classpath" in static block"

```
class A {
    static final String classPath;
    static {
        try {
            classPath = new ClassPathResource("").getFile().toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I circumvent or untie it? Thx

Comment: You probably forgot the case where you have an exception. `classPath` won't be initialised.

Comment: Did you get the exception stacktrace printed?

Comment: @Thilo it's a compilation error.

Comment: If you not able to do something it is useful to add an error message from compiler or program execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not assigning the variable in the exception case.

Assuming that you actually need the value of `classPath` to be correct, you may as well throw an exception, to indicate that something has gone terminally wrong, and this class cannot be used:

```
static {
  try {
    classPath = ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

(And if you don't actually need it, remove the field!)

---

Whilst it doesn't make sense to set a default value, it's instructive to look at why you can't set one in the catch block.

```
  try {
    classPath = ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
    classPath = defaultValue;  // classPath may already be assigned.
  }
```

This is because of [the rules of *definite assignment* for try statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.15):

> V is definitely unassigned before a catch block iff all of the following are true:
>
> - V is definitely unassigned after the try block.
> - ...

So, without looking at the other things which must be true, `V` is not definitely unassigned after the try block (i.e. if the assignment succeeds), so it is not definitely unassigned in the catch block; as such, you can't assign another value.

---

Note that if you want to assign a default value, you would need to either assign a local variable first:

```
String classPath;
try {
  classPath = ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  classPath = defaultValue;
}
A.classPath = classPath;
```

Or define a static method:

```
class A {
  static final String classPath = getClassPath();

  static String getClassPath() {
    try {
      return ...;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }
}
```

(The advantage of the latter being that you can invoke it in unit tests; the disadvantage is that it breaks checking that any static variables used in the method (or other methods called) are actually initialized).

Answer (score 1):

The logic is correct, but you need to initialize the value not matter what. Here, in case of an exception, you don't do it.

You need to manage the case where you have an exception :

1. Default value ( a valid is better ! )

Of course, you can't just write two statement that would instantiate it, you can use a local variable

```
String s;
try{
    s = new ClassPathResource("").getFile().toString();
} catch (IOException e){
    s = MyDefaultValue;
}
classPath = s;
```

Or let a static method to do it for you (to much logic in a static block is messy)

2. throw a `RuntimeException`, this will be valid and will stop the execution. (Thanks @Andy Turner and his [example](https://ideone.com/TLbaN3))

Comment: Better to throw a runtime exception; presumably you need the value of `classPath` later, so setting it to null is just kicking the failure down the road.

Comment: @AndyTurner indeed! but still need to instantiate it I believe. I never throw an exception in a static block ...

Comment: If i assign any value in catch block then it is giving this error - "The final field classPath may already have been assigned"

Comment: @user2600472 if you want to assign a default value (and I'd recommend you don't), I would make it into a static method, and then initialize the field from the result of that method, rather than in a static initializer block.

Comment: @AndyTurner if you have the time, you can write your answer. I am trying to edit mine but I don't feel I can answer this with the best approch... my knowledge about static block is mostly theorical ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
class A {    
private static final String classPath;
        static {
            String tempPath=null;
            try {
                tempPath=new ClassPathResource("").getFile().toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            classPath=tempPath;
        }
  }
```

It will work.

Comment: I hope that you don't use variables whose names differ only in case in real code... At a glance, it looks like you're assigning the `classPath` variable multiple times in this code. So, sure, it works, but it's confusing.